# Console based command processing: Mapping string to enum in java

Tags: java

For my java console application, I need to call a set of functions with user given arguments. My operations O1, O2, .. O5 are defined as an enum as

```
enum Operations {O1, O2, O3, O4, O5};
```

I need to read user input args[0] and call function F1, F2,...F5.

For example user is going to give:

```
>java MyApp O1 5 6
```

For this I suppose I need to map sting (args[0]) to an  enum so that I can use switch select. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enum.valueOf(Class, String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29).

Example

```
Operations oper = Enum.valueOf(Operations.class, args[0]);
```

Will throw an exception if there are no enum values that matches `args[0]`

Comment: why not `Operations oper = Operations.valueOf(args[0])`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose using what chuk lee 's lead you can come up with pritty cool program
here what I did.

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    if(args.length < NUMBER_OF_OPERATORS){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(INSUFFICIENT_OPERANDS); 
    }

    Operator operator = Enum.valueOf(Operator.class,
                                         args[OPERATION_NAME].toUpperCase());

    System.out.println(operator.operate(args[FIRST_OPERAND],
                                                   args[SECOND_OPERAND]));


}


private enum Operator {

    ADD,SUBSTRACT,MULTIPLY,DIVIDE;

    public String operate(String aString, String bString) {

        int a = Integer.valueOf(aString);
        int b = Integer.valueOf(bString);

        int out = 0;


        switch(this) {


            case ADD    : out = a + b; break;
            case SUBSTRACT  : out = a - b; break;
            case MULTIPLY   : out = a * b; break;
            case DIVIDE : out = a / b; break;
            default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        return String.valueOf(out);
    }

}

private static final int NUMBER_OF_OPERATORS = 3;
private static final int OPERATION_NAME = 0;
private static final int FIRST_OPERAND = 1;
private static final int SECOND_OPERAND = 2;
private static final String INSUFFICIENT_OPERANDS = 
                           "Insufficient operads to carry out the operation.";
```

}